# Polarity of Methyl Radical

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is methyl free radical a polar molecule?
According to Advanced Organic Chemistry by Jerry March, it is given as non-polar.
But then wat about the moment of the single electron?

Comment: The methyl free radical is trigonal planar, hence the non-polarity.

Comment: What is the definition of polarity in chemistry? It does not mean anything specific despite its common use. You would rather ask, does methyl free radical have an electrical dipole moment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused see firstly methyl free radical is a planar with two hydrogens facing each other . The dipole moment vector of the single electron is away from the central carbon

Carbon has Electronegativity value 2.55 while for H it is 2.2 so all the hydrogens have a small positive charge and the carbon has a small negative charge . the direction of the dipole is from negative to positive so the dipole moment vector of the single electron egts cancelled by the resultant of that of the C-H bonds hence it is a non polar structure

[image: so u see those two hydrogens facing each other their dipole gets cancelled the dipole of the single electron gets cancelled by that of the 3 rd hydrogen]